# Progressive image format

Tags: javascript, image, web, image-manipulation, image-resizing

I'm developing an artist portfolio website and displaying a lot of paintings on it organized by collections. To speed up loading time, I'm looking for a progressive image compression format that would allow me to decompress and render on the fly a picture such as I can render it at scale .5 when half of the picture data has been received.

I know JPEG has a progressive option, but I didn't find out how to transmit and decode it partially (I think that's the browser job, but then again I read that not all of them support this feature so I don't know where to look to find an example).

The idea is to be able to serve pictures that have just the resolution the client need without having to store differents scaled size of the same picture on the server and witout the need for the client to download the same picture twice each time (original and thumbnail).

Comment: It doesn’t work that way. You can not simply say, I load half of the data and display it at half the size – and hope that that actually works. If you use progressive/interlaced, then it is the browser’s job to render the image in more detail as more details become available – and that is not necessarily a two-step thing, first step half the quality, second step full quality … no. Storage space _is_ cheap – so storing different size versions of the images and letting the client choose the appropriate one _is_ the way to go. Research “responsive images”, `picture` element and polyfills for it.

Comment: While storage space is cheap bandwidth isn't and reducing load time while improving responsiveness seams like an interesting things. We can imagine for example a device going from portrait mode to paysage and a larger picture being updated over the data from the smaller one. I

Comment: _“While storage space is cheap bandwidth isn't”_ – yes, and that’s why you want to serve images of appropriate dimensions, and not “one size fits all”.

Comment: Thanks for mentionning polyfils which I didn't know. I think I will use it.